# Extending generic collection

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, design-patterns, collections

Is there anything wrong with extending a generic class just to simplify or prevent writing redundant code?

Basically what I want to do is

```
class EnityGroup extends LinkedList<Entity>
{
    ....
}
```

but every example I've seen composition seems to be preferred.

What, if any, are the issues, concerns, conflicts etc that I would have to worry about.

Comment: Where is this paranoid coming from?

Comment: @texasbruce I've seen this pattern many times, but it is always composition being used. I even found some text books and even they use composition over inheritance (at least when using generics). I think it's silly, but Java isn't my best language so I figure something I don't know might bite my in the ass.

Comment: Guess it depends on your use case. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a type alias, a feature available in other programming languages (eg. C or C++). Java doesn't provide such feature.

For the type system `EntityGroup` [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `LinkedList<Entity>` so nothing bad can happen. Every method that accepts a `LinkedList<Entity>` will accept an `EntityGroup` instance.

The only shortcoming is that the constructors are not directly available to your subclass so you are forced to redeclare them (possibly forwarding arguments to superclass constructor).

From a polymorphic point of view this is not like having a type alias, since `EntityGroup` is a different type which extends another type, not a different name for `LinkedList<Entity>`. So `LinkedList.class != EntityGroup.class`, this could create problems with code that uses reflection, unless written correctly to automatically detects types in the hierarchy.

Inheritance is there to enrich or specialize behavior of a class, which is not the case in this situation. You are basically using a feature to obtain something that is not meant to be obtained in this way, but by having type aliases, which unfortunately aren't available in Java.

Comment: For the most part, I am thinking about a type alias (with a few added functions to special handling). I just thought this technique made most sense but I never see it done....so I was curious. Really the only argument I've heard against inheritance is that in my case its not a pure is-a relationship only mostly.